# meteorjs how to import a wrapbootstrap theme

Tags: css, meteor, less

I have a meteorjs app with the bootstrap3-less package.

I want to apply a theme to this app. Therefore I have some css stylesheets.

I included these stylesheets into my stylesheets directory but it doesn't work because they are loaded after my .less files (even though they are alphabetically bigger).

I tried to change the extension of these files to .import.less and to import them into my main.less files.

This works but then the auto-reload becomes extremely slow (18 seconds.). So this is not an option.

Any idea how I could get these files to load after main.less? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refering to [import .css file into .less file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196915/import-css-file-into-less-file) 
in your main.less:

```
@import (css) "bootstrap_theme.css";
```

Comment: Good trick but it adds @import on top of the less file and I need it after because it's an extend of the bootstrap classes.

Comment: Check customized usage section https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less : try to copy bootstrap.import.less and rename it to bootstrap.less to override config and add at the end of bootstrap.less string from answer.

Comment: This is doing the trick! I don't even needed to add the import at the end as it is loaded in the right order now. I don't think that you may do it. If I'm not wrong, it's a css convention to put imports on top of css files. Many thanks!