# LESS @import (css) "file.css" puts the css at the top of the output

Tags: html, css, less

Take the following less file, call it style.less:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    #IMPORT
\*------------------------------------*/

/**
 * CSS files
 */

@import (css) "../css/bootstrap.css";
```

Look at the generated style.css then I see bootstrap css file at the top, followed by the comments.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Less moves CSS imports to the top since by the spec. they must precede any other rules (except `@charset`). Meanwhile comments are not considered by Less to be tied to any particular statement so their position/order may not be preserved. The simplest workaround I can think of right now is to move all your non-Less code having a formatting you wish to preserve into a separate file and import it with `@import (inline)`.

Comment: Thank @seven-phases-max I'll edit the generated file a little rather than put into a separate file. I think it's best :D

Answer (score 0):

You can import css like regular @import or inject the css(bootstrap.css) content to new generated css file (style.css)
[import-css-file-into-less-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196915/import-css-file-into-less-file)