# Less: process less and CSS files

Tags: css, less

I've a project with less and CSS files mixed (vendor stuff). I want to optimize all files either CSS or less to one merged CSS file. Usually I've one less file which imports all needed files. But it doesn't work with imported CSS files. It just export the "import "foo.css"" to the merged CSS file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196915/import-css-file-into-less-file

Comment: @donnywals: sort of.  The question is answered by one of the answers at the question you linked to, but as an aside: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22594082/16777  The question itself I think is different enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@import (inline)` directive. 
You can read more about it [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-inline).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to treat `.css` files imported like they would be `.less` with the following syntax:

```
@import (less) "foo.css";
```

This results in a final compiled `.css` file that include rows from original `.css` imported one, followed by processed LESS rows.