# Import .css file in Less using nodejs gulp

Tags: css, node.js, less, gulp, gulp-less

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196915/import-css-file-into-less-file) it's possible to import css file from less v.1.4.0.
I tried to use `gulp-less` task, and it's not working.
There's any way to import css file like this: `@import "../spritesheet.css";` with nodeJS gulp?

Comment: Define "it's not working"? What is it that you're trying to achieve exactly? Do you need to access classes defined in the .css file for re-use in the .less file?

Comment: events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Broken @import declaration of "../spritesheet.css"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to include files in LESS, depending on what you need, using `@import ([keyword]) "filename"`.

Allowed keywords are:

> - reference: use a Less file but do not output it
> - inline: include the source file in the output but do not process it
> - less: treat the file as a Less file, no matter what the file extension
> - css: treat the file as a CSS file, no matter what the file extension
> - once: only include the file once (this is default behavior)
> - multiple: include the file multiple times
> - optional: continue compiling when file is not found

[Lesscss.org - Import Options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options)

It's not clear to me what your use case is, but if you want to use the contents of `spritesheet.css` further on in your LESS file (for example extending classes defined in your spritesheet) you need the `(less)` keyword.

If you just want to include the contents of `spritesheet.css` into your output file without accessing them from within the LESS file at all, stick with `(inline)`.

Comment: @import (inline) is the answer!!  Thanks!!