# Is there a way to tell less-css/gulp-less to leave an @import rule as-is

Tags: css, less, gulp-less

I'd like the css file produced by the less compiler to contain an `@import` directive at the beginning of the file.

I.e. given this less file:

```
@import "external.css" /* this import directive should be left as is */
@import "globals.less"
a { color: @linkColor; } /* defined in globals.less */
```

the resulting CSS file should look like this:

```
@import "external.css"
a { color: #00a; }
```

It seems that none of the various [options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options) of the less import directive helps producing this. Is there any other way?

---

Update: I'm using [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) to compile the less files. It might be a problem with that package and not with less itself (`@import (css) "external.css";` doesn't give the desired result).

Comment: What's the problem with importing `external.css` giving the output without LESS processing?

Comment: Reading the [manual: `@import "foo.css";  // statement left in place, as-is`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature#import-directives-feature-file-extensions), shouldn't `@import "external.css"` already be *left as is*? Maybe it's a bit picky with regards to the closing `;`?

Comment: @Yoshi: It is picky with regards to the closing `;` but in that case it would give a syntax error during compilation. When the `css` keyword is used, it would leave the import statement as-is (from v1.4 upwards).

Comment: @Yoshi: I read that part of the manual, but it doesn't work. Maybe it's a problem of gulp-less?

Comment: @M4N: Just to help in my search, can you let me know what happens when the `@import` is used without any options and with the `(css)` option? Does it give any errors (or) does it put the entire content into the file (or) ?

Comment: @Harry: using `(css)` or `(inline)` or no option has no effect. The contents of external.css is always included in the resulting css file.

Comment: @M4N: Are you including any libraries like this one in your build process - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport (these seem to replace the import statements with actual content)?

Comment: @Harry: no, I have gulp-less, gulp-clean-css and gulp-sourcemaps only

Comment: @M4N: Hmm, I don't have any other updates then :( Guess we will have to wait for somebody else to come and answer. I am leaving my answer as-is because there is no Less question for leaving the import statement as-is either.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd posted you `gulp`-script. I'm pretty sure the issue has nothing to do with Less at all and it's something in your `gulp` toolchain doing this (e.g. some css-minfier for example).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: that was it! The `@import` was processed/resolved by the gulp-clean-css task following the less compilation. If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *[seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638098/is-there-a-way-to-tell-less-css-gulp-less-to-leave-an-import-rule-as-is?noredirect=1#comment66705910_39638098)* guessed (in the comments), this issue was not caused by `gulp-less`, but by the css-minifier (`gulp-clean-css`) which ran after the gulp compilation.

Using the correct clean-css options (`processImport: false`) solves the problem.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a similar plugin to the gulp-cssimport that I linked in my comment earlier. Good that you've found the reason.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** It does seem to be a gulp-less problem (or some other library in the chain) because the code in question should actually output the `@import` statement as-is even without using the `(css)` option. [The Less compiler seems to be capable of reading the file extension and if it is `css` then it just leaves the `@import` directive as-is](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature-file-extensions). So, this should definitely not be a Less compiler issue.

---

Yes, try using the `css` keyword like `@import (css) "external.css";`. When this keyword is used, the Less compiler would output the import statement as-is.

```
@import (css) "external.css";
@import "globals.less";
a { 
  color: @linkColor; 
}
```

would compile to

```
@import "external.css";
a {
  color: #00a;
}
```

Comment: But this will produce the code in `external.css` will output "as-is", but not leave the `@import` sentence

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you @MarcosPérezGude. Please try at lesscss.org :)

Comment: You're right, I'm guessing that the compiler would include the inner code on `external.css` into the final result. But it's fine. Thank you :)

Comment: That's fine @MarcosPérezGude. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. See updated question - maybe it's a problem in gulp-less.

Comment: Probably yes @M4N. Does this thread help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727449/import-css-file-in-less-using-nodejs-gulp. The comment seems to indicate that it works only for `inline` (which is different behavior) but give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: @M4N: I've done a bit of searching and couldn't find any related gulp-less issue threads/fixes. I've never used gulp-less and so don't know much about it. I'll update the answer if I manage to find any relevant info.