# Grunt/less @imports are not imported in the Outputfile css

Tags: import, gruntjs, less

My Imports are not imported in the outputted main.css file, normally main.css should be filled with the css of bootstrap, fontawesome, animate etecetera...

but they are showing up like this `@import "bootstrap.min.css";@import "font-awesome.min.css";@import "animate.css";...`

This is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

    var userConfig = require( './build.config.js' );

    var taskConfig = {
        watch: {
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= less_dir %>/**/*.less'], // which files to watch
                tasks: [ 'less'],
                options: {
                    nospawn: true
                }
            }
        },

        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true,
                    optimization: 2
                },
                files: {
                    "<%= css_dir %>/main.css": "<%= less_dir %>/main.less"
                }
            }
        }
    };


    grunt.initConfig( grunt.util._.extend( taskConfig, userConfig ) );

};
```

My main.less

```
/* - Imports - */
@import "bootstrap.min.css";
@import "font-awesome.min.css";
@import "animate.css";
@import "variables";
```

Comment: See [Import Options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196915.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it fixed! I'm going to answer my own question so If you random stranger have the same problem you only have to change the filename from *.css to *.less to actually trigger grunt-contrib-less to import your stylesheet

So `bootstrap.min.css` to `bootstrap.min.less` / etc...

Comment: Don't rename, use either `(inline)` or `(less)` instead.

Comment: I have tried that but It seems to only work on the Original Less, not grunt-contrib-less

Comment: `grunt-contrib-less` uses exactly the same compiler code as "original" one so it can be no difference. Re-check (also considering your very ancient `gruntfile.js` snippet above - none of three less options used there are valid anymore - make sure you use an up-to-date `grunt-contrib-less` version and not some hello from the middle ages).

Comment: Could you explain the part "Ancient gruntfile.js"?

Comment: By now neither `yuicompress` nor `optimization` options have any effect (they were removed more than two years ago). And `compress` is also deprecated (as it is incompatible with recent CSS developments and to be removed at any moment).

Comment: Wow I didn't know about that, could you direct me somewhere where I can see the new functions that could be useful for me for less?

Comment: Well, all currently valid `grunt-contrib-less` options are documented right at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#options. These options map to the native Less compiler lib options documented [there](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-options) (different names are used because of different console/JS naming conventions). And finally `lessc --help` also lists all currently available options (including warnings about deprecated stuff).